# Make carousel icon (preview and next) have the same colour when hovered and visited

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, hover, carousel

When I hovered on one of the carousel items (or click on them), they get a darker colour than when they are unvisited. I would like them to have the same colour in those situations. However, I do not know how to do this. I've tried using colour and background but none of them make any changes.

Thanks in advance for helping this newbie!

```
.container {
  padding: 15rem;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 20rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.carousel-inner {
  min-height: 150px;
}

.carousel-item {
  margin-block-start: 3.5rem;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    display: none !important;
}

.carousel-icon {
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    filter: invert(50%);
}

.carousel-icon:link,
.carousel-icon:visited,
.carousel-icon:hover,
.carousel-icon:active, {
  /* color: red; */
  /* background-color: red; */
  background: red;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Carousel</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-carousel.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"integrity = "sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin = "anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- jQuery Library -->
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity = "sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin = "anonymous">
    </script>

    <!-- Popper -->
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity = "sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin = "anonymous">
    </script>

    <!-- Compiled and Minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity = "sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin = "anonymous">
    </script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <p>"In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis."</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <p>"Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis."</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <p>"Sed velit dignissim sodales."</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon carousel-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon carousel-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background-image` is an `SVG`, I therefore recommend that you use [`stroke="currentcolor"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes) but 
only if you absolutely have to deal with this situation you can trick it using [drop-shadow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) and [translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) add this to your code:

```
.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: .99!important;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon{
    filter: drop-shadow(32px 0px 0px red);
    transform: translate(-32px, 0px);
}
.carousel-control-next-icon{
    filter: drop-shadow(-32px 0px 0px red);
    transform: translate(32px, 0px);
}
```

if you are only talking about the opacity then add this only:

```
.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev { 
    opacity: .99!important;
}
```

here is a demo

```css
.container {
  padding: 15rem;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 20rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


.carousel-inner {
  min-height: 150px;
}

.carousel-item {
  margin-block-start: 3.5rem;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    display: none !important;
}

.carousel-icon {
    height: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem; 
}

.carousel-icon:link,
.carousel-icon:visited,
.carousel-icon:hover,
.carousel-icon:active, {
  /* color: red; */
  /* background-color: red; */
  background: red;
}

.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: .99!important;
}
.carousel-control-prev-icon{
    filter: drop-shadow(32px 0px 0px red);
    transform: translate(-32px, 0px);
}
.carousel-control-next-icon{
    filter: drop-shadow(-32px 0px 0px red);
    transform: translate(32px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Carousel</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-carousel.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"integrity = "sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin = "anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- jQuery Library -->
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity = "sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin = "anonymous">
    </script>

    <!-- Popper -->
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity = "sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin = "anonymous">
    </script>

    <!-- Compiled and Minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity = "sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin = "anonymous">
    </script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <p>"In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis."</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <p>"Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis."</p>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <p>"Sed velit dignissim sodales."</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon carousel-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon carousel-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the **opacity** property of the *carousel-control-prev* and *carousel-control-next* class for various states of the link that is its **link, visited, active, and hover** state. By default the opacity value of these classes is set to 0.5 so on hover it changes to 0.9 that's why the darkening effect is happening.